# How to persist data in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and trying to get familiar with it without spending 40 hours on a training course.

I can spin up a container based on an image and it's working fine , but if I run docker commit , something like

```
docker container commit -m "postinstall, web3" a6a5be991ca5 web3
```

If I look at the volume tab in kitematic , it doesn't appear to have any volume assoiciated with it, and so I am having a hard time seeing the process / logic behind what it's doing and I fear that I will restart the machine and my files / data will be lost.

How can I keep these images persistent once I take a snapshot ( docker commit )  of them?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You should read this. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ It's about how you map a docker volume to your local machine so when you stop and start the docker container all the data is persisted

Comment: no offence, but you really need to read the link that @RonNabuurs gave you if you want to use Docker

Comment: Thanks ,   @RonNabuurs , yes I have read it many times.. I just can't seem to make sense of it.  For example docker container run -d --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="password" -v mysql:var/lib/mysql mysql:5.6.23  ;  I do see a named volume - but the mounts part of the volume does not contain any destination field.

Comment: in `-v mysql:var/lib/mysql` the part after `:` - `var/lib/mysql` is the mount part in the container. part before (here `mysql`) can be your host machine path (e.g. `/home/user/mysql`) or the name of a volume (folder) that docker will create in it's data folder

Comment: @MartinThompson make sure you type the paths correctly so `/var/lib/mysql` and not without the slash. Also make sure to map the correct path to your own system like Miq said. An example could be this `docker run -d --name mysql -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.6.23`